# Is it possible to set editText drawableLeft to null?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edittext and according to the code I get from web service I need to set drawable right to my edittext.

I get the response code by calling a service as soon as the edittext focus changes, so if the edittext gain focus again the image should be gone as well.

But if the response code is different from these cases I need to set that drawable as transparent, null or I have to make it's visibility gone.

```
                        ediTextAbc.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.abc,0,0,0);
```

Comment: Pass `0` as id .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Set 0 or null where you don't want drawable**

**Try  :**

```
ediTextIbanEft.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

**OR**

```
ediTextIbanEft.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Yes setting null will help you ege-kuzubasioglu

Answer (score 1):

In `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0, 0);`

set 0 where you don't want drawable.

Comment: I want to remove that drawable so `ediTextIbanEft.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);`

should work

Comment: Yes, passing argument as 0 will remove the drawable.